# How to create histogram for below data in R

Tags: r, histogram

My Dataframe with 4 obs with 6 variables

```
  MonthYr : 202101 202102 202103 202104
  Count1 : 123456 123425 123452 123455
  Count2 : 123456 123429 123453 123454
  Count3 : 123455 123428 123455 123455
  Count4 : 123455 123428 123455 123455
  Count5 : 123455 123428 123455 123455
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fl2b.png)
Added image I want as my graph. And the its growing, If I run code next month new count would be auto added for month of May and onwards.

Can some one help me to histogram code in R?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: What is your intended output? Do you want to have one histogram for each variable in your data? One histogram per month? Something else?

Comment: This seems to be count data and not continuous data. I believe you need a bargraph and not a histogram

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, please don't assume non-base packages in your question edits, there is nothing to suggest OP is using `tibble`. Frankly, it isn't obvious to me that it's a `data.frame`, it could be six vectors. In this case, I suggest it's best to ask that the OP provide usable data and not just a description of the data.

Comment: Yes, One histogram per month for each counts, x=MonthYr  & y= all counts buildings. you guys understand what I mean? I'm new to R. learning from you 
 all, So I need experts help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really make a histogram with so few datapoints, but you could visualize the distribution of each "Count" variable using boxplots, e.g.

```
# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(MonthYr = c(202101, 202102, 202103, 202104),
           Count1 = c(123456, 123425, 123452, 123455),
           Count2 = c(123456, 123429, 123453, 123454),
           Count3 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455),
           Count4 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455),
           Count5 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455))

# Make MonthYr a factor
df$MonthYr = factor(x = df$MonthYr,
       levels = c("202101", "202102", "202103", "202104"),
       labels = c("Jan - 2021", "Feb - 2021", "Mar - 2021", "Apr - 2021"))

# Reshape the dataframe to the "long" format
df2 <- reshape(df, varying = 2:6, v.names = c("Value"),
        direction = "long")

# Plot the distribution of Counts for each MonthYr
plot(x = df2$MonthYr, y = df2$Value, xlab = "Month - Year",
     ylab = "Values", main = "Distribution of Counts for each Timepoint")
```

[image: example_1.png]

For histograms:

```
"Jan 2021" <- df2$Value[df2$MonthYr == "Jan - 2021"]
"Feb 2021" <- df2$Value[df2$MonthYr == "Feb - 2021"]
"Mar 2021" <- df2$Value[df2$MonthYr == "Mar - 2021"]
"Apr 2021" <- df2$Value[df2$MonthYr == "Apr - 2021"]
dev.off()
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
hist(`Jan 2021`, las = 2, xlab = "")
hist(`Feb 2021`, las = 2, xlab = "")
hist(`Mar 2021`, las = 2, xlab = "")
hist(`Apr 2021`, las = 2, xlab = "")
```

[image: example_2.png]

### Edit

You can plot all 4 histograms on the same plot using e.g.

```
breaks <- seq(min(df2$Value), max(df2$Value), 0.5)
yaxis <- seq(1, 4, length.out = 20)
plot(x = df2$Value, y = yaxis, type = "n", ylab = "Count", xlab = "Value")
hist(`Jan 2021`, add = TRUE, breaks = breaks, col = 1, border = 1)
hist(`Feb 2021`, add = TRUE, breaks = breaks, col = 2, border = 2)
hist(`Mar 2021`, add = TRUE, breaks = breaks + 0.33, col = 3, border = 3)
hist(`Apr 2021`, add = TRUE, breaks = breaks + 0.66, col = 4, border = 4)
legend("topleft", c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"), fill = 1:4)
```

[image: example_3.png]

However, you can see that they overlap (I used a small offset in the breaks so they don't overlap completely). I think a better way of handling it would be to use [ggplot graphics library](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html):

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Value, fill = MonthYr)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

[image: example_4.png]

Or, stacked side-by-side:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Value, fill = MonthYr)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image: example_5.png]

Or facetted:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Value, fill = MonthYr)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~MonthYr)
```

[image: example_6.png]

### EDIT 2:

Based on your comment below and the picture you have now provided, you don't want a histogram: you want a barchart/barplot. Here is an example of a barplot using the ggplot library

```
# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(MonthYr = c(202101, 202102, 202103, 202104),
           Count1 = c(123456, 123425, 123452, 123455),
           Count2 = c(123456, 123429, 123453, 123454),
           Count3 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455),
           Count4 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455),
           Count5 = c(123455, 123428, 123455, 123455))

# Make MonthYr a factor
df$MonthYr = factor(x = df$MonthYr,
       levels = c("202101", "202102", "202103", "202104"),
       labels = c("Jan - 2021", "Feb - 2021", "Mar - 2021", "Apr - 2021"))

# Reshape the dataframe to the "long" format
df2 <- reshape(df, varying = 2:6, v.names = c("Value"),
        direction = "long")

df2$Count <- factor(df2$time,
                   levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   labels = c("Count 1", "Count 2", "Count 3", "Count 4", "Count 5"))
df2

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = MonthYr, y = Value, fill = Count)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.7), stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(123405, 123460)) +
  theme_dark(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")

table_theme <- ttheme_default(base_size = 14, padding = unit(c(8, 8), "mm"))
table1 <- tableGrob(df, rows = NULL, theme = table_theme)
grid.arrange(plot1, table1, nrow = 2, heights = c(1, 0.75))
```

[image: example_7.png]

Comment: Thank you, Histograms looks great, Can its be done in one histogram instead of 1 for each month. I'm trying to get 1 histogram for 4 different counts to display and same for second month and so on. I'm learning R, So please bare with me.

Comment: Overlaid in different colors?

Comment: Yes, Overlaid in different colors

Comment: @Jared_Mamrot, Thank you. I added image in my question. Is this can be done in R? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, yes - that is a bargraph/barplot. Like @Onyambu said in his comment above, that is a much better/easier way to visualize the data

Comment: @Jared_Mamrot, Perfect, Appreciate your help. Thank you.